# ERC20 token via openzeppelin, mint() always stuck?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin, mint

I've created a erc20 token using `openzeppelin`, and deployed to `rinkeby` testnet.

When I call `mint()`, it always stuck, e.g:

```
await contract.mint('0x............',ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5")
...
```

I've already added the address to the whiltelist.
Any idea ?

**Contract code:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20BurnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract FreeBirdTokenV3 is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20BurnableUpgradeable, PausableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    mapping(address => bool) whitelistedAddresses;

    function addUser(address _addressToWhitelist) public onlyOwner {
        whitelistedAddresses[_addressToWhitelist] = true;
    }

    function verifyUser(address _whitelistedAddress) public view returns (bool) {
        bool userIsWhitelisted = whitelistedAddresses[_whitelistedAddress];
        return userIsWhitelisted;
    }

    function initialize() initializer public {
        __ERC20_init("FreeBirdToken", "FBT");
        _mint(_msgSender(), 10_000_000);
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        __Pausable_init();
        __Ownable_init();
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(verifyUser(to));
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
    internal
    whenNotPaused
    override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but consider not using Rinkeby anymore, since it will become deprecated soon (due to the Merge). Switch to the Goerli.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, would you recommend Sepolia Testnet in addition in Goerli? Dev team promised leave it too after the Merge.

Comment: I don't know about Sepolia so I can't say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, in `hardhat`, the amount param for `mint()` is in ether, should pass `BigInt`.

e.g:

> await fbt.mint('0xe38fE38eB33950E21Fa9419178A27C9Be553330A',100n * (10n ** 18n))

Now it succeed:
[image: mint transaction]